# angular-translate: using translate directive and filter together

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am making use of the variable replacement feature from angular-translate in my application as documented in the guides [here](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement)

Using the example in this guide, I was wondering how you could translate an interpolated value being passed in. So say I have something as follows for displaying some validation text to the user.

**html**

```
<div ng-message="required" translate="REQUIRED_FIELD" translate-value-field="Description"></div>
```

**locale file**

```
{
  "REQUIRED_FIELD": "{{field}} is required",
}
```

A problem I see with this is that `Description` is being used literally and therefore not translated.

Could a filter be used for the value being assigned to the `translate-value-*` directive like so:

**html**

```
<div ng-message="required" translate="REQUIRED_FIELD" translate-value-field="{{'GENERAL_TERMS.DESCRIPTION' | translate}}"></div>
```

**locale file**

```
{
  "REQUIRED_FIELD": "{{field}} is required",
  "GENERAL_TERMS": {
        "DESCRIPTION": "Description"
    }
}
```

This does work for me locally, but I wondered whether this approach is correct.

Can anyone offer any advice please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me locally

html tag

```
<div ng-message="required" translate="REQUIRED_FIELD" translate-value-field="{{'TESTKEY' | translate}}"></div>
```

with input

```
{
  "REQUIRED_FIELD": "{{field}} is required",
  "TESTKEY": "Name"
}
```

so your approach seems to be correct.

Maybe the problem lies with the translation namespace **GENERAL_TERMS.DESCRIPTION** key?